# Increasing number of columns fails datatable in php

Tags: php, datatable

im having table reading values from database using PDO and display it in table,Then finally i used Datatable javascript code.Now my table having pagination,searching option.
But now i want to include one more column as 'Action' to do edit, delete fucntion.When i include these fifth column as Action. Then my table appears as normal..not as datatable format (pagination,searching option is not there). My coding below:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("header.php");
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM auditplan";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=BASE_URL?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=BASE_URL?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/jquery2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?=BASE_URL?>themecss/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<?=BASE_URL?>themejs/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="<?=BASE_URL?>themejs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="<?=BASE_URL?>themejs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
   <h1 class="page-header"> Audit Plan </h1>
   <a href="Auditplanentry.php" class="btn btn-primary" >Add New</a>
   <table class="table table-striped"  id="auditplantbl">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Audit ID</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php
          foreach($result as $row){ ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['auditid']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['year'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['month'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['comment']?></td>
         </tr>
         <?php  }
        ?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#auditplantbl').dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 columns in your table header but only 5 in your body, you need to match the same number of columns in your header and body for datatable to work fine.

You need to add one in the body to add the buttons or whatever you were planning to do to delete or edit your items :

```
<?php
foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['auditid']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['year'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['month'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['status']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['comment']?></td>          
      <td> edit link / delete link </td>
      </tr>
<?php  }
```

Comment: Yes,before i include <td>, without adding <th>.Same error.So i delete that <td> and add both <th> and <td> same thing happened.but now i changed,its working. thanks.